# Type-casting of session object in python, django

Tags: python, django, casting

I would like to ask something about tyoe casting in python, Django.
I have a `CompanyReview` object in session `request.session['review_company_review']` and I would like to get this object.
I have written the code below but I consider there should be a better way.

```
cr = CompanyReview()
cr = request.session['review_company_review']
```

Could you give me any idea how I can cast my session object to companyreview object ?

PS: I try to do `cr = ComapnyReview(request.session['review_company_review'])` but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: As long something is pickable in Python it can be saved in a session (see Python's `pickle` module: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). This is usually the case for Django model instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any type-casting in Python.

If you have saved that object to session doing like `request.session['review_company_review'] = some_company_review_object`, to retrieve that object you can just do:

```
cr = request.session['review_company_review']
```

Comment: Ok but I would like to use properties of CompanyReview class. After I get the cr object , I want to know which attributes CompanyReview has..

Comment: @brsbilgic unless you have code of `CompanyReview` class, attributes of its objects you can get only at runtime (e.g. using `dir`).

Comment: @brsbilgic if you do know attributes of `CompanyReview`, nothing stops to write something like `request.session['review_company_review'].do_something_usefull()`